# How to take data from a form in order to search and filter in MongoDB

Tags: python, django, mongodb

I am trying to take the data from a form in order to use that data as a filter and redirect to the page that contains the table with all the filtered data. I am using Django 1.10.5, Python 3.6 and MongoDB with Pymongo. I don't want to save the data of the form, I just need it for the filtering. This is what I have done:

<---Views--->

```
def BuscaProyecto(request):
form = FormBuscaProyecto(request.GET or None)
if form.is_valid():     
    datos = Proyectos.objects.filter(AñoPresentación__icontains=AñoPresentación & Status__icontains=Status)
return render_to_response(request, 'blog/detail.html', {'datos':datos}))
```

<---html--->

```
<div id="Proyectos">                            
                        <form action="" method="get" role="form">
                            {% csrf_token %}
                            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 centered">                          

                                <!-- Año de Presentación -->    
                                <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 centered">
                                    <div class="form-group">                                
                                        <input name="AñoPresentación" type="date" class="form-control"/>                                        
                                    </div>
                                </div>                                                                   
                            </div>                              

                            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 centered">  
                            <!-- Status -->
                                <div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-2 centered">

                                    <label for="Status" class="control-label">Status</label>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 centered">                    
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <select id="Status" name="Status" class="selectpicker form-control" data-width="100%" style="display">
                                            <option value="APROBADO">Aprobado</option>
                                            <option value="DENEGADO">Denegado</option>                                    
                                        </select>
                                    </div>                                           
                                </div>
                            </div>  
                            <!-- Botón de Buscar -->
                            <div class="centered">  
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
                                    Buscar
                                </button>                           
                            </div>
```

Comment: Do you want to display datos in template ?

Comment: Yes! In a table, in another template, but I don't know if I have to pass the parameters through url or with the GET method..

Answer (score 0):

After the form.valid return the datos to another template

```
If form.is_valid():
    ....
    return render(request, 'another_template', {'datos': datos})
```